# How to set up dnx builds on CCNet? dnu runs but fails with "dnx not found"

Tags: asp.net-core, cruisecontrol.net, dnx, .net-core

I'm trying to set up some ASPNetv5 builds on CCNet. I added an exec block like this:

```xml
<cb:define name="DnuPackageRestore">
    <exec>
        <executable>dnu</executable>
        <cb:ifdef name="SourceFolder">
            <baseDirectory>$(SourceFolder)</baseDirectory>
        </cb:ifdef>
        <cb:else>
            <baseDirectory>$(WorkingPath)\$(ProjectName)</baseDirectory>
        </cb:else>
        <description>DNU Package Restore</description>
        <buildArgs>restore</buildArgs>
    </exec>
</cb:define>
```

For some strange reason, CCNet fails for .cmd files in PATH, so I changed `executable` from `dnu` to `dnu.cmd`. It now runs dnu fine but that immediately crashes saying it can't find dnx:

```
2016-03-02 14:17:19,073 [SuperThing:DEBUG] Starting process [dnu.cmd] in working directory [D:\CI\W\SuperThing] with arguments [restore]
2016-03-02 14:17:19,076 [SuperThing:DEBUG] Not setting PriorityClass on [D:\CI\W\SuperThing\dnu.cmd] to default Normal
2016-03-02 14:17:19,091 [13:DEBUG] [SuperThing dnu.cmd] '"D:\CI\W\SuperThing\dnx"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2016-03-02 14:17:19,091 [13:DEBUG] [SuperThing dnu.cmd] operable program or batch file.
```

It claims to be looking in `SuperThing` for dnx, but since it says the same for dnu.cmd I think that's a red herring.

If I PowerShell remote into the server as the same user, everything works fine (I installed dnvm, let it install `1.0.0-rc1-update1` and I ran `dnvm set default -p`).

There's seemingly something wonky with how CCNet is executing this `dnu.cmd` that's causing it to fail (my guess is a PATH is getting lost somewhere?).

Comment: Is `dnu` added to the path? If not, can you run `dnvm upgrade/install` before running `dnu`?

Comment: It is in the path - both remote PoSh and logging on via RDPas this user both commands work fine. Managed to resolve by doing as Andrew Nurse suggested (I had tried this, as we had it for some other commands, but clearly I didn't do it right!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can't execute ".cmd" files using standard Process.Start (not sure if CCNet does that). Instead, you need to exec `cmd` with arguments `/c [path to cmd file]`. Perhaps try that and see if it resolves the issue?

Comment: Ugh... I'm sure I tried this yesterday and thought it had the same result as adding ".cmd" (eg., the first one - dnu.cmd - worked, but then it crashed calling dnx). However, I just tried again and it has worked... I suspect maybe I misread the error and I did that before restarting CCNet (so it didn't have the updated path, and was crashing on dnu, not dnx). Thanks! :)

Comment: Just checked my checkin... I missed the /C from the args on this one yesterday (despite it being in the NPM one). Doh!